# Cannot consume web service with JQuery (console issues cors but xml is returned)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, http, cross-domain

I am trying to consume a web service with JQuery and I am getting the weird result of the browser showing cors error on the console while in the response tab I can see the returned XML.

See my console

[image]

See my response

[image]

The web service that I am trying to access calculate the freight of products.
I don't know how web services work, It's strange that it is blocked somehow, as the purpose of web services is to provide access to applications.

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
   <script>
        $().ready(function () {


                var sendjson = {
                    "nCdEmpresa": "",
                    "sDsSenha": "",
                    "nCdServico": "41106",
                    "sCepOrigem": "37540000",
                    "sCepDestino": "37540000",
                    "nVlPeso": "1",
                    "nCdFormato": "1",
                    "nVlComprimento": "20",
                    "nVlAltura": "5",
                    "nVlLargura": "15",
                    "nVlDiametro": "0",
                    "sCdMaoPropria": "s",
                    "nVlValorDeclarado": "200",
                    "sCdAvisoRecebimento": "s"
                }



                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",

                    cors: true,
                    url: "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx/CalcPrecoPrazo",
                    data: sendjson,
                    dataType: "application/xml",


                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function (data, err)
                    {
                        alert(err);
                    }

                });
        });
    </script>
```

If someone can give me directions how to consume this web services I will be very glad. The answer can be in C# too, using HttpClient or whatever.

Comment: this is a CORS issue,  try adding a property in the ajax request as follows             `crossDomain: true` instead of `cors: true`

Answer (score -2):

you need to replace your ajax call parameters

```
cors : true  to crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'application/xml' to contentType : 'application/xml'
```

Ajax Call :

```
         $.ajax({
                type: "GET",

                crossDomain: true,
                url: "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx/CalcPrecoPrazo",
                data: sendjson,
                contentType : 'application/xml',


                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data, err)
                {
                    alert(err);
                }

            });
```

Comment: This also does not work for me, I think that the server has to be aware and send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, in my case the server is not sending it, I get the same error as the OP, `(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)`

Comment: The problem is because the server is not returning the required CORS headers. The client request (and by proxy any additional headers/data sent) is irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: it's working on my computer by changing both headers.